# Is the rate of radioactive decay inversely proportional to the stability of an isotope?

Tags: radioactivity

Is the rate of radioactive decay inversely proportional to stability of the isotope?

Comment: How are you measuring stability, if not by decay rate (or half-life)?

Comment: @PM2Ring - perhaps one could interpret 'stability' to mean  the Q-value of the reaction?

Comment: @JonCuster Certainly! But I'm still waiting for Eman to clarify that. Perhaps they want to know about the relationship between Q-value and half-life...

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340659/why-is-caesium-137-more-stable-than-caesium-134 shows that decay rates are impacted by various factors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - by definition, the stability of an isotope is measured by its lifetime.